# Using sticky bits (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, permissions, root, python3, libertine

I'm using nmap on Ubuntu 16.04 (arm) where nmap is using raw sockets to perform
certain tasks.

I've encountered weird problem though. I can't seem to get it to work with root privileges nor
with sticky bit (`chmod u+s script.py`) applied to it.

Please see below:

as root:

[image]

with sticky bit applied:

[image]

errored out anyway:

[image]

Can I get an assistance on this ? I'm really cornered. I'm running this script within Libertine container which I'm not 100% sure if it's relevant piece of information.

Comment: Sticky bit has no effects on files. What you are setting using `+s` is not sticky bit. it's `suid` and `suid` has no effect on shell scripts As a security measurement.

Comment: I've got a Python script but I guess that makes no difference.

Comment: I've got no idea why your first attempt (using root to open a python shell) does not work. my comment were only about `sticky` and `suid` bits. And yeah `suid` does not work on any kind of scripts. Shell, Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: @Ravexina  I'm running this on 16.04 but within Libertine container which is a piece of information that I'm about to include in my post as it may be important in order to answer this.